# Why does my JavaScript code get a “No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource”

Tags: javascript

I am trying to do authorization using js by connecting to the RESTful API built in Flask. However, when I make the request, I get the following error:

I know that the api or remote must set the header, but why did it work when I made the request via the Chrome extension?

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'text',
    url: api,
    username: '',
    password: '',
    crossDomain : true,
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    }
})
    .done(function( data ) {
        console.log("done");
    })
    .fail( function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
        alert();
    });
```

Comment: When you make the request with an extension, you are not running your code in the context of a website, but rather as a standalone application. Only Ajax calls from a website trigger CORS issues

Comment: Your Chrome extension never sends `Origin` header. AJAX calls does though.

Comment: I edited the post to remove what appears to be an at best a spurious link, and at worst a spam attempt masquerading as a real question.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `crossDomain: true` when the API is being served from the same host as the JS...

because it appears to be a bogus warning, caused by this one setting.